# SDL header file cannot be found

Tags: xcode, macos, sdl

I am having trouble configuring my SDL library for a program that I would like to start on. I am getting the error "Cannot find SDL.H"

[image]
[image]

I thought I installed it correctly, but I am still getting this error.
I followed a tutorial online exactly but did not get the same results.

Comment: Are you using the right import statement? It should be #import <SDL2/SDL.h>

Comment: I thought it was #include #import <SDL2/SDL.h> didn't work

Comment: Do you get the same error when you use #import?

Comment: yes I got the same error while using #import I don't see how mine would not work if I did exactly what someone else did to no avail.

Comment: 2 things I can think of, off the top of my head:

1) The framework file isn't actually in /Library/Frameworks. It could be in ~/Library/Frameworks, for example. You can right-click on SDL2.framework and select "Show in finder" to see where the linked framework is located.  2) Xcode is working with outdated information and you need to clean the project and delete derived data.

Comment: I have tried changing it to ~/Library/Frameworks already. and I just downloaded the Xcode just before attempting to load SDL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try copying the header file into the Xcode project.